# Why doesn't equality involving “minus” typecheck in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

Why won't the following typecheck:

```
minusReduces : (n : Nat) -> n `minus` Z = n
minusReduces n = Refl
```

Yet this will typecheck fine:

```
plusReduces : (n : Nat) -> Z `plus` n = n
plusReduces n = Refl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`minus n` doesn't reduce because `minus` is [defined](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/3c31a7ef860932c95b8db8d9d03e05a4f1d19d02/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L72) with pattern matching on the first argument:

```
total minus : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
minus Z        right     = Z
minus left     Z         = left
minus (S left) (S right) = minus left right
```

So you'll need to split your `Z` and `S n` cases as well:

```
minusReduces : (n : Nat) -> n `minus` Z = n
minusReduces Z = Refl
minusReduces (S k) = Refl
```

Comment: It works. Though I am still confusing. There is a `minus left     Z         = left` clause, I can't see how it is split on the first argument.

Comment: Yeah but you first have to fall through the `minus Z right` case to get there! Remember the cases are ordered.

Comment: Interesting. The behavior is different from implicit resolution rules in shapeless/Scala.